# Preprocessor for shared files for two different builds on the same view

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I am using visual DSP for two different builds. I am using preprocessors to separate out code that is specific to each in shared files. I was planning to use the built-in preprocessor utility on the project files, but the project files specific to one build is not linked to another so this is not working. Is the only other simple way to preprocess the code in my build script?

Comment: I saw this soon after it arrived, and concluded I didn't know what you were asking about.  Given that noone else has responded either, I'm beginning to suspect I'm not alone in not understanding your scenario.  Is "Visual DSP" something to do with MS Visual Studio?  Perhaps you should illustrate more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Visual DSP is a program used for embedded software for DSP processors. I was wondering if it was possible to set the preprocessor in the build script instead of in the project files directly since I will have so many overlaps of files. If I go the project file route, do I need to have two different project files instead of the same one?

Comment: Succinctly, I have no idea; I don't understand the context in which you're working.